# Setting up the auth middleware in Laravrel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

I would like to know how can I set up my **auth** middleware in laravel 5.4.I am trying to set up the redirect route in

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

but there is no chages.
Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware probably works as is but you will still need to enable this. Information regarding registering middleware can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware) but in short:

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
];
```

This will name your middleware "guest" (which might already be enabled if you executed `php artisan make:auth` beforehand.

Then you will need to apply it this can be done in 1 of 2 ways.

On the route.

1. Directly
   `Route::get('admin/profile', 'AdminController@show')->middleware('guest');`
2. With groups
   `Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {//other routes});`